# Test for using spread operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My problem is with creating a test that will see if the user input is correct. By that I mean that if the user has used a spread operator to solve a problem.

I tried covering this by using some regex. For example; if the user uses the `push` function with spread operator like this `.push([...arr]]` this regex will match

```
\.push\s*?=\s*?\(\s*?\[\s*?\.\.\.\s*?\]\s*?\)
```

But the problem here is that the user can use different ways to solve the problem and I can't see a way to handle all of the possible inputs. I just need an idea. Here is the code that the user must change and use a spread operator:

```
function copyMachine(arr,num){
    let newArr=[];
    while(num >=1){
    // change code below this line 

    //change code above this line
    num--;
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(copyMachine([true, false, true], 2));
```

Comment: This is not about unit-testing. A unit test is for automated testing of code. What you do is more like a programmer quiz. Therefore I have removed the unit-testing tag.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but does that make sense? Assuming the `copyMachine` function is a template you provide, for a user to write `newArr.push([...arr])` doesn't make sense for two reasons: It produces the wrong result (it _should result in `[true, false]`, right? But `.push([...arr])` results in `[[true, false, true], [true, false, true]]`)_ and completely ignores your template. Therefor, check for: 1) An intact template & 2) Use a `RegExp` to see if the provided solution matches _what you expect_.